# There is an unwanted close curly brace in the preferences page

Tags: bug, status-completed, preferences

There is an unwanted close curly brace in the [preferences page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/preferences/current), in between the **Custom Question Lists** and **Advertisements** section.

**Preferences page**:

> [image: preferences]

When view the page source, I can see the curly brace. So may be a developer wrongly placed it.

**View Page Source:**

> [image: view source]

Comment: Haha good spot, IMO a developer probs spent hours looking for the missing close then gave up threw another one in purely because they opened php one line late :D

Comment: This is end without a beginning. We're doomed! }

Comment: to wound the autumnal city. }

Comment: `$('.inner-container[data-alpha-feature-name="CustomQuestionLists"]').before("{");` - restore the balance! }

Comment: Cross-site post on Meta.SO: [There's a lone curly brace on the preferences tab](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/385390/4642212).

Comment: Related: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/9145/15479

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I am happy to report that the offending `}` is gone.